# jquery saving data until phonegap app closes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to write data to a storage that gets erased when phonegap mobile app closes?
I used localStorage (html5) but this data does not get erased when app closes. How could I save data that last until app closes and I can't save it to variable because I use a lot of .js files and methods and don't want to pass all this variables with parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try cookies or if the data is too big for a cookie, perhaps [HTML 5 sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp) would help